# Helmet is not working to set security headers for static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, response-headers, helmet.js

I am using loopback , for setting header inside server.js I'm using helmet but its only working for api's but not for static files. What might be the probable cause of this?

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. This usually happens because you're using Helmet on your API routes but not others. Are you using Helmet at the top level of your app? Are you serving static files outside of Express?

Comment: Will the order of server.use make a difference? e.g. server.use('public followed by server.use(helmet? Should it be server.use(helmet followed by server.use('public?